# How do I make a row of 5 <divs> responsive using percentage widths?

Tags: css, html, width, padding

I have created a widget consisting of a row of five floating `div`s, each containing an image. Here's a stripped-down version of the HTML:

```
<div class="panel">
  <img src="/images/image.jpg" height="160" width="160">
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <img src="/images/image.jpg" height="160" width="160">
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <img src="/images/image.jpg" height="160" width="160">
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <img src="/images/image.jpg" height="160" width="160">
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <img src="/images/image.jpg" height="160" width="160">
</div>
```

And here's a stripped-down version of the CSS:

```
.panel {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
height: 160px;
position: relative;
margin: 8px 25px 0 0;
width: 160px;
}
```

The five `div`s are in a container (original width of 940px - changes to `width: auto` when the screen width is reduced below 940px) with a left and right padding (20px each side).

I have used media queries to create a responsive stylesheet but I now want to make the floating `div`s fit to the screen as the width is reduced.

Does anyone know how I could do this, please?

Comment: Check your code. The img tag has not been closed properly. Also provide a sceenshot of how you want it to be.

Comment: I am coding in HTML5 and, as imgs are void elements, they don't need to be closed:

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#void-elements

Comment: Check this snippet from your code. `"/images/image.jpg height="160"` The brace is incomplete under the `src` Do you think this is correct? - @DomStapleton. And FYI, I am not talking about the closing tag. May be the words made the misunderstanding.

Comment: Beg your pardon, Nathan; I've fixed the code. Thanks for letting me know.

Just to reassure you, the src attribute is closed correctly on my site! I just forgot to add the closing quotes when I was stripping the code down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you're looking for, but maybe just using `calc()` would be the best way to handle it all.

```
.panel {
  float: left;
  height: 160px;
  width: calc(20% - 25px);
  margin: 8px 25px 0 0;  
}
```

You don't need for this any other position than the default `static` one. It also doesn't makes any sense set the display to `inline-block` when you float an element, because it would be more like a block element.

For the container you would maybe do something like this:

```
.container {
  width: 940px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

So it will be a *responsive thing*.

You can see the `calc()` compatibility here: http://caniuse.com/calc

Comment: Thanks, pzin. I'll give this a go and let you know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If the container `div` is given a fixed `width`, then the page can't be responsive. If you change that to a `max-width` or remove the width property altogether, then the panels should wrap.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made this clearer: the parent `div` is 940px when the screen width is wider than that, but is changed to `width: auto` when the screen width falls below 940px.

Comment: Ah. That probably renders my answer useless then!

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.leftdiv {
width:100%!important;
height:100%!important;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
.right-div {
width: 100%!important;
margin-left: 0!important;
height:100%!important;
}
}
```